# Is there any theorem telling how to construct a group whose congruence lattice is modular but nondistributive?

Tags: group-theory, algorithms, order-theory, universal-algebra

Is there any theorem telling how to construct a group whose congruence lattice is modular but nondistributive?

I don't mean searching for a result with a use of the computer. I know that probably it requires "going through" normal subgroups, but my knowledge of group theory is almost non-existent.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: the congruence lattice of a group is always modular

Comment: There's a theorem due to Ore that says the lattice of all subgroups of a group is distributive iff the group is locally cyclic. This answers the question for abelian groups.

Comment: @Eran Of course, and I had meanwhile answered with that result, confusing congruence lattice with subgroup lattice!